# I have 4000 data frames inside a list. want to apply summarise function using group_by on each dataframe of list

Tags: r, dplyr

Summarize one column (rainfall) of data frame present inside a list using group by function by using another variable already present in each data frame. I want to find maximum rainfall value for each year by using the function group_by.

Comment: Use group_by and summarise function on each data frame of a list.Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example